# Amazon lex Runtime Operations

Tags: amazon-lex

when I was using Amazon Runtime service as an API for PostText/PostContent operations, I observed that you can enter only the user input that the lex matches with the utterances, I need to know whether we can fill the slot values using the lex API PostText/PostContent operations?

The reason i was using Lex runtime service is that Lex doesn't support filling slot types of user location(latitude and longitude) and i was using another webhook(nodejs server, i will get coordinates when a user sends location) to connect to the facebook messenger bot, then  i will call Lex Rutime service!

Answer (score 0):

You can not fill the slots using the PostText/PostContent operations. You will have to use AWS.LexModelBuildingService.

The way this works, create an intent on the console, select a lambda for for initialization and validation. This will get called when the intent gets activated and then inside your Lambda you can fill out slots depending on user's input.

You can also use a Lambda in Fulfillment, but this will only get called when all **required slots** and filled. If you have several slots but they are not required, the Fulfillment will be called automatically in the first try.